# Simple_form is blank! Shows nothing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, simple-form

I'm working on an mailer with rails, but where It should be shown the fields it shows nothing.

the view is:

```
<% simple_form_for(@message, :url => mailer_new_path) do |f| %>
  <%= f.error_notification%>
  <div class="inputs">
    <%=f.input :subject, :hint => "Write the subject here!"%>
    <%=f.input :body, :as => :text%>
  <div class="actions"%>
    <%=f.button :submit , 'Send Email', :class => "primary btn"%>
<% end%>
```

the mailer_controller:

```
class MailerController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @message = Message.new
  end
end
```

message.rb:

```
class Message
  include MongoMapper::Document

  key :username, String
  key :subject, String
  key :body, String
  #validates_presence_of :username, :body
end
```

In routes I have:

```
get "mailer/new"
get "mailer/create"
```

Can someone help me please?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of:

```
<% simple_form_for(@message, :url => mailer_new_path) do |f| %>
```

you should have:

```
<%= simple_form_for(@message, :url => mailer_new_path) do |f| %>
```

The difference is this `<%=`.

It would be ok in Rails 2. In Rails 3/4 you should put `=` before calling any view helper, even if you pass block to it.

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
<%= simple_form_for(@message, :url => mailer_new_path) do |f| %>
```

Answer (score 1):

`<% %>` is for any Ruby code, but doesn't output the results (e.g. if statements)

`<%= %>` is for outputting the results of Ruby code (e.g. values from the model)

`<%- and -%>` suppress leading and trailing whitespace

`<%# %>` is an ERB comment

Answer (score 0):

Spot the difference

```
<%= simple_form_for(@message, :url => mailer_new_path) do |f| %>
```

Comment: @mcjoejoe0911 Not the best question either. It's a typo, should be closed. I encourage you to vote for closing!

Comment: I find your suggestion valid and will do just that!